# Tell facebook not to parse URL's in my app posts

Tags: php, facebook

I have an application that posts some sold domain names to our facebook page. Sometimes if the domain sold actually have a website, facebook is crawling this website and adding a snapshot to our post, but we don't want this, as we're only interested in the domain, and we don't want that some day some porn appears in our posts or something.

So the question is, is there a variable that I can pass to facebook to tell it not to parse any URL in my posts? I notices that if updating my status on facebook, and I paste a URL, facebook parses it, but I can still click an X button to tell facebook not to, so there should be a way to do the same for an app posting.

Comment: Are you able to programmatically just delete the snapshots (which can be done manually)?

Comment: nope. I am trying to find a workaround to make facebook either not parse anything at all or take a snapshot of our website.

Comment: @admdrew do you know if this same thing can be done on twitter? like I post test.com it doesn't become http://test.com

Comment: I am really not sure, I would have to test with the SDK or do some research online.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting, AFAIK. Facebook tracks all the URLs posted by your application. Facebook probably conducts a series of checks to determine if it's allowable in a post. This is probably a security feature to help prevent people from being directed to phishing pages, or other sites with malicious content.

To resolve this issue, you can check the HTTP Referrer (and/or the IP address) for those tracking scripts and add a check in your application code to discard the data if the HTTP Referrer source is Facebook.

Comment: do you know if this same thing can be done on twitter? like I post test.com it doesn't become test.com

Comment: @CodeBird: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: same question for facebook but on twitter, like if I tweet test.com tell twitter not to add http:// before it and link it to test.com website